# WebBrowser авторизация по сертификату

Tags: c#

Добрый день.
В системе установлено несколько цифровых сертификатов.
Необходимо в приложении с помощью WebBrowser авторизоваться на определенном сайте не выбирая сертификат, а чтобы автоматически в запрос передавался нужный, что касается авторизации логина пароля и какие параметры передаются понятно.

```
string data = "ReturnUrl=&Login="+login+"&Password="+password+"&send=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8";
Site.Navigate("ссылка", "_self", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Вопрос какой параметр передается в post при авторизации помощью сертификатов в WebBrowser (возможно это серийный номер отпечаток).

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать свой прокси, который будет устанавливать ssl соединение, а webBrowser будет через него общаться.
Второй вариант - статья [Suppressing Hosted WebBrowser Control Dialogs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31163/Suppressing-Hosted-WebBrowser-Control-Dialogs)

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.